# How to copy one image to another in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

This is picture of my "Avatar" tab on my `Registration.cshtml` page:

[image]

I want to copy selected image from this image slider to this bigger image above slider.

Here is my code in `Registration.cshtml`:

```
<div id="copiedimage">
  <img class="default-avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png")" alt='default-avatar' />
 </div>
        <div class="slider">
          <img class="avatar selected" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar.png")" alt='avatar' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_dog.png")" alt='dog' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_chihuahua.png")" alt='chihuahua' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_black_cat.png")" alt='black_cat' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_kitten.png")" alt='black_cat' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_mouse.png")" alt='black_cat' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_horse.png")" alt='horse' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_pig.png")" alt='horse' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_blue_bird.png")" alt='blue_bird' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_cow.png")" alt='cow' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_green_fish.png")" alt='green_fish' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_shark.png")" alt='shark' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_crab.png")" alt='crab' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_dolphin.png")" alt='dolphin' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_octopus.png")" alt='octopus' />
          <img class="avatar" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Account/avatar_seal.png")" alt='octopus' />
        </div>
```

I don't know if this is important, but my application is in `MVC5`.

Do you need more details about something? I have jquery for this slider, should I use jquery? Or maybe it can be done in razor? Maybe images should be in form of buttons? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the selected image is the only one that has css class `selected`, try this:

```js
var img1 = $('.slider .avatar.selected')[0];
var img2 = $('#copiedimage img')[0];
img2.src = img1.src;
img2.alt = img1.alt;
```

```css
.avatar.selected {
  border: solid 2px blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="copiedimage">
  Selected image:
  <img class="default-avatar" src="" alt='default-avatar' />
</div>
<br/>
<div class="slider">
  Slider:
  <img class="avatar selected" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1osH.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt='user1' />
  <img class="avatar" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMxg.jpg?s=32&g=1" alt='user2' />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, selected image is the only one that has css class `selected`... 
But after this code I have error in my console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.bxSlider (jquery.bxslider.js:1528)...

Comment: I created a code snippet to demonstrate that it works. It could be that your code deviates from what you put in the question, you'll then have modify the selectors used in the `$('.....')` calls that retrieve the image elements from the page.

Comment: Thank you, I accidentally typed something in my div as I expected answer on my question, so your code works perfectly! This is link for additional click function with adding and removing selected class  ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/Bjelke/osk404kx/53/